# Comparison of unicode characters in xsl:if

Tags: xslt, unicode, arabic

i have this block of xslt if-else case and was wondering if there's a way for me to do straight comparison with unicode character?

Something along the lines of the code shown below? Or does xslt have some built in function which i can use for this purpose? i.e. change the unicode into html entities and compare via that method?

Of course if there's a better way please fire away.
Thanks.

```
<xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="status">
                            <xsl:if test="status='تم المحاولة'">
                                <font color="#00CC00"><xsl:value-of select="status" /></font><br/>
                <!--a href="/Elearning_Platform/xfiles/reports/view_reports.modcgi?asm_lid={@lom_id}&amp;did={@dispatch_id}&amp;rm_student_id={@person_id}&amp;report_type=2">[View Results]</a-->
                            </xsl:if>
</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            &nbsp;
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both the source XML and the XSLT are declared as UTF-8 encoded i believe this shouldnt be a problem. If your parser supports EXSLT you can call url-decode(status) directly
[this resource](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N3353.html#d4848e330) has some examples + makes a good read about encoding in XSLT in general.

Comment: well actually i tried to do direct xsl:if test var=[some arabic text], but it didn't work. And i'm using putty, could this be the cause? thanks.

Comment: I do not think that the encoding of the source XML and the XSLT program matter. XSLt works on the infoset, not on the text representation.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is positive**.

**More precisely**, **[any character that can be used within an XML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#charsets)**, can be used as part of an argument to an **[XPath equality comparison operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#NT-EqualityExpr)**.